# How to use ';' (semicolon) in urls, using Google Appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url

Using the local dev server, I can use ';' in urls, but as soon as I try the live version hosted by Google, it looks like the ';' and everything afterward is stripped (at least according to `request.path_qs`).

(I would prefer not to encode them if possible, it's much less user friendly if the url cannot be constructed by copy-pasting, especially since other characters works fine, e.g. ':').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue816 has now been fixed, semi-colons are usable with appengine.

Answer (score 3):

It is a known issue: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=816
So I am afraid you need to use a workaround.

Comment: Hopefully this will get fix soon now :)